# Why can't I creat a file in "/" or main Directory in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to create a file in "/" directory (which contains bin, boot , cdrom, dev, etc) but I am unable to do so. Although I am the one who install ubuntu and I am the root user? The error I get is of permission denied.

Also I cannot calculate the hash of a file in this directory.

I am sorry for my lame question as I just have switched to linux after using windows for long time.

Comment: try checking your UID: `echo $UID` if your UID is not 0, you can't write to "/". Try `sudo echo $UID` and you should see the response `0`

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, you're certainly not a "root user" (ubuntu does not have one) - so you don't have rights to create anything there. Which is a GOOD thing. You can "override" this using `sudo` command: `sudo mkdir /SomeDir` - but you most certainly shouldn't. Put your data in your home directory. That's why it's there. Also, this is not the right place to ask. Try it here: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @JanSpurny: Ubuntu certainly does have a `root` user; that account just doesn't have a password by default. But you're right, there's rarely any reason to create files in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the action but prefix your commands with `sudo` . Or if this is happening in a custom program you have written, execute that under `sudo`